# collect() taking a long time to run

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have been using `tbl()%>%collect()` to retrieve data from an ODBC-connected database for a while now. Several days ago, `collect()` started taking an extremely long time -- over 10 minutes. The size of the data didn't appreciably increase (it's under 1 million rows), and it still runs efficiently for my coworkers. I've tried re-installing dplyr, but it didn't help.

Any advice on what might be causing this or how I can troubleshoot?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the versions of packages being used on yours and the other machines, notably `dplyr` and `dbplyr` to start. Also look into ODBC driver versions in case you (inadvertently?) updated it. It might help to directly compare `sessionInfo()` from multiple machines to look for varying components.